# Spring Boot is ignoring my CORS configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I have a REST API with CORS enabled, but it seems like Spring Boot is ignoring my CORS configuration. Here it is the configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Value(value = "${cors.allowed-origins}")
    private List<String> allowedOrigins;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable().cors().configurationSource(this.corsConfigurationSource()).and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(this.allowedOrigins);

        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(
            HttpMethod.GET.name(), HttpMethod.POST.name(), HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
            HttpMethod.DELETE.name(), HttpMethod.HEAD.name(), HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name()
        ));

        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList(
            HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, HttpHeaders.ACCEPT,
            HttpHeaders.ORIGIN, HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD, HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS,
            HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION
        ));

        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList(
            HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD,
            HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, HttpHeaders.ORIGIN, HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION
        ));

        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
}
```

And here it is the Spring Boot application class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class RaioXcapeBackend {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RaioXcapeBackend.class, args);
    }
}
```

I know that the CORS configuration is not being applied because the API is allowing requests from any origin (e.g.: I send a `GET` request from my local running front-end), but my goal is to allow only from one origin, which is my deployed front-end application domain.

What could be happening? I've already checked the `${cors.allowed-origins}`, and it's correct.

**UPDATE 1**

Below are the headers of a `GET` request to the API.

```
Response Headers

Cache-Control:          no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection:             keep-alive
Content-Type:           application/json
Date:                   Mon, 19 Jun 2023 22:58:41 GMT
Expires:                0
Keep-Alive:             timeout=60
Pragma:                 no-cache
Transfer-Encoding:      chunked
Vary:                   Access-Control-Request-Headers
Vary:                   Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary:                   Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options:        DENY
X-Xss-Protection:       0

Request Headers

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,pt;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Dnt: 1
Host: localhost:8080
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: first remove this `.configurationSource(this.corsConfigurationSource())` since you have declared it as a `@Bean` the framework will apply it automatically. Second, `know that the CORS configuration is not being applied because the API is allowing requests from any origin` this cant be true, since if there is no CORS configuration the browser will deny all requests. Please update your question with the headers from a successful request to the backend

Comment: @Toerktumlare I've added the headers to my question and removed the `.configurationSource(this.corsConfigurationSource())` line, but it didn't make any difference. I hope the headers helps.

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is missing from the response headers and as you can see I'm sending it in my code.

Comment: how are you doing your request? the vary: Origin header is telling you that you need to include the origin header in your request. This is usually done automatic unless you are doing your request in some strange way. If you are doing curl read this https://reqbin.com/req/c-taimahsa/curl-cors-request

Comment: I'm not using `curl`, I'm sending through Postman and doing nothing with it, keeping it the default. Also, I don't have NGINX  or any proxy set up. I really don't know what's happening.

Comment: Before, I was sending the requests through Google, by typing the endpoint, and the results were the same.

Comment: Look what I found: [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#:~:text=Vary%20headers%20are%20added%20for%20non%2DCORS%20requests%20on%20CORS%20endpoints). Since I'm running all from my own machine (`localhost`), it means that I won't be able to test CORS. I have to deploy both backend and frontend applications and test after, right?

Comment: But doing requests from postman will ignore CORS, cors is only enforced in browsers

Comment: Are you positive that allowedOrigins list is not empty and taking the defined values from properties file.

Comment: @SachinMewar I'm 100% sure! I'm printing the list inside `corsConfigurationSource` and its state is as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Place `@EnableWebMvc` at Controller Level.

Place url value in `application.properties`

Below is the code that you can use as configuration.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;    

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable().cors().configurationSource(this.corsConfigurationSource()).and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(this.allowedOrigins);

        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(
            HttpMethod.GET.name(), HttpMethod.POST.name(), HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
            HttpMethod.DELETE.name(), HttpMethod.HEAD.name(), HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name()
        ));

        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList(
            HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, HttpHeaders.ACCEPT,
            HttpHeaders.ORIGIN, HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD, HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS,
            HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION
        ));

        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList(
            HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD,
            HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, HttpHeaders.ORIGIN, HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION
        ));

        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    
        String origins = environment.getProperty("url");
    
        registry.addMapping("/v1/**")
            .allowedMethods("PATCH","GET", "POST", "OPTIONS","PUT", "DELETE")
            .allowedOrigins(origins.split(","))
            .allowedHeaders("*").allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just using Spring boot annotation on the head of my class that implement the enpoind`@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200/", maxAge = 3600)[enter image description here][1]`